# How do I integrate react-navigation with an existing tab view component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabview

I would like to use React Navigation with a tab view component that is not its default tab view (the one I have chosen to use is [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view), as it provides a much more comprehensive interface for customization of its appearance).  However, I just don't seem to be able to understand the documentation for writing custom [navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators.html) and [routers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-routers).  What are the basic steps I will need to perform this integration?  How is this going to be affected by the fact that I will need to be able to compose a `StackNavigator` inside of some of my tab view's tabs?

Comment: Which version of react-navigation are you using? I'm using 1.5.0 and  react-native-tab-view is their default tab view component, so I think you dont have to do anything special?

Comment: @MarsonMao - while it does seem that their tab navigator is in fact based on react-native-tab-view, several of the standard properties aren't exposed (e.g. `renderIndicator`), and I need to configure these properties in order to achieve the design I'm working on.  Although perhaps rather than a custom tab view it might be easier to modify their adapter layer to support these properties...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MarsonMao in the comments, the default implementation is based on react-native-tab-view.  Unfortunately, it didn't provide the hooks I needed to make it work, but I was able to make a subclass of `TabBarTop` with a copy of the original `render` function modified to include the change I needed.